# how to fix this snowflake SQL compilation error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
SQL Error [1003] [42000]: SQL compilation error:
parse error line 1 at position 28 near '95'.
  SQL compilation error:
parse error line 1 at position 28 near '95'.
  SQL compilation error:
parse error line 1 at position 28 near '95'.
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "REPLICA_RtHSNMaster"("PARAM_STG_SUFFIX" VARCHAR(200), "TEMP_TBL_ID" VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(5000)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '
  
 var var_temp_table_name = `TEMP_RtHSNMaster_`+ TEMP_TBL_ID;
  
 var sql_command = `CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE ` + var_temp_table_name;
  sql_command += ` AS SELECT * FROM RTHSNMASTER LIMIT 0 `;
       
        snowflake.execute (
            {sqlText: sql_command}
            );

    
 sql_command =`COPY INTO ` + var_temp_table_name;
  sql_command += ` FROM @DATA_FILE_S3_STAGE` + PARAM_STG_SUFFIX;
 sql_command +=` PATTERN =$$.*RtHSNMaster_.*csv$$ FILE_FORMAT =(FORMAT_NAME =$$CSV_FORMAT$$ FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = $$"$$ TIMESTAMP_FORMAT =$$YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF$$);`;
       // FORCE = TRUE;
       
        snowflake.execute (
            {sqlText: sql_command}
            );
            

    
    sql_command =`DELETE FROM RTHSNMASTER using ` + var_temp_table_name;
  sql_command += ` WHERE RTHSNMASTER.TENANTCODE=` + var_temp_table_name;
  sql_command += `.TENANTCODE AND RTHSNMASTER.HSNID=` + var_temp_table_name;
  sql_command += `.HSNID ; `;
       
        snowflake.execute (
            {sqlText: sql_command}
            );

    
 sql_command =`INSERT INTO RTHSNMASTER SELECT * FROM ` + var_temp_table_name;
        
        snowflake.execute (
            {sqlText: sql_command}
            );

    
    
    var success ="Data insert/update in rthsnmaster table";

    return  success;
    ';
```

Hi, I am getting this above error while trying to view, store procedure data in snow flake. Can somebody help me on this issue .
This happens after I updated the DBeaver version. Only Store procedure has this issue other data i can view through code.

Comment: There is obviously an issue with the code in your SP but as you haven't posted the code no-one is going to be able help help you. Also, what command are you running when you try and view the SP?

Comment: You need to provide a query/code for this then only anyone will help you out.

Comment: edited pls check

Comment: @NickW there is no issue with the code. The scheduler works fine.

Comment: If there is no issue with the code (i.e. it is running successfully via some command) then what is the command (and where are you running it, etc.) that is giving the SQL error you are showing in your question?

Comment: @NickW it is a task. Running every hour. It just calls the stored procedure. Yes, it shows SQL error that's what I am asking here why it shows like that?

Comment: In your original question you said you got this error when viewing the SP, in an earlier comment you said “there is no issue with the code” and now you seem to be saying that this error happens when the SP is run by a scheduled task. Please update your question to provide a detailed, clear, unambiguous explanation of exactly what is happening/running when you see this error - as all the conflicting information you’ve provided so far is just causing confusion

Answer (score 0):

So I took your Stored proc, and I loaded it into my instance.

I altered it a tiny bit to use 4 different variable, and to also return those bits of SQL and made it note execute it ether.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REPLICA_RtHSNMaster(PARAM_STG_SUFFIX VARCHAR, TEMP_TBL_ID VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '
  
var var_temp_table_name = `TEMP_RtHSNMaster_`+ TEMP_TBL_ID;
  
var sql_command1 = `CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE ` + var_temp_table_name;
sql_command1 += ` AS SELECT * FROM RTHSNMASTER LIMIT 0 `;
       
//snowflake.execute ( {sqlText: sql_command1} );

var sql_command2 =`COPY INTO ` + var_temp_table_name;
sql_command2 += ` FROM @DATA_FILE_S3_STAGE` + PARAM_STG_SUFFIX;
sql_command2 +=` PATTERN =$$.*RtHSNMaster_.*csv$$ FILE_FORMAT =(FORMAT_NAME =$$CSV_FORMAT$$ FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = $$"$$ TIMESTAMP_FORMAT =$$YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF$$);`;
       
//snowflake.execute ({sqlText: sql_command2});
            
var sql_command3 =`DELETE FROM RTHSNMASTER using ` + var_temp_table_name;
sql_command3 += ` WHERE RTHSNMASTER.TENANTCODE=` + var_temp_table_name;
sql_command3 += `.TENANTCODE AND RTHSNMASTER.HSNID=` + var_temp_table_name;
sql_command3 += `.HSNID ; `;
       
//snowflake.execute ( {sqlText: sql_command3} );

var sql_command4 =`INSERT INTO RTHSNMASTER SELECT * FROM ` + var_temp_table_name;
        
//snowflake.execute ( {sqlText: sql_command4} );

var success = sql_command1 + `\r\n` + sql_command2 + `\r\n` + sql_command3 + `\r\n` + sql_command4 + `\r\n`; 

return  success;
';
```

Then I ran it:

```
call REPLICA_RTHSNMASTER ('A', 'B');
```

which gave this SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_RtHSNMaster_B AS SELECT * FROM RTHSNMASTER LIMIT 0;  

COPY INTO TEMP_RtHSNMaster_B FROM @DATA_FILE_S3_STAGEA PATTERN =$$.*RtHSNMaster_.*csv$$ FILE_FORMAT =(FORMAT_NAME =$$CSV_FORMAT$$ FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = $$"$$ TIMESTAMP_FORMAT =$$YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF$$); 

DELETE FROM RTHSNMASTER using TEMP_RtHSNMaster_B WHERE RTHSNMASTER.TENANTCODE=TEMP_RtHSNMaster_B.TENANTCODE AND RTHSNMASTER.HSNID=TEMP_RtHSNMaster_B.HSNID ;  

INSERT INTO RTHSNMASTER SELECT * FROM TEMP_RtHSNMaster_B
```

I then create some objects so each line would run:

```
CREATE TABLE RTHSNMASTER(TENANTCODE int, hsnid int, extra_value int);
CREATE STAGE DATA_FILE_S3_STAGEA;
CREATE FILE FORMAT CSV_FORMAT;
```

and all four lines ran, albeit I had no data in my empty stage.

As an aside that DELETE/INSERT could just be a UPSERT via a MERGE command.

Anyways I thought the error message, might happen if a string with whitespace was passed in.

so I changed the first command to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_RtHSNMaster_ 95 AS SELECT * FROM RTHSNMASTER LIMIT 0;
```

and in SnowSight I get the error:

> Syntax error: unexpected '95'. (line 42)

which not similar, but I went back into classic console and looking at the error there it is:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 52 unexpected '95'. syntax error line 1 at position 52 unexpected '95'.

which matches much better. and position 28 is where the second SQL puts the `TEMP_TBL_ID` so I am not sure why the create is passing and it is failing on the second line.

So to workaround this you ether want to trim you varaibles.

```
var var_temp_table_name = `TEMP_RtHSNMaster_`+ TEMP_TBL_ID.trim();
```

OR double quote them:

```
var var_temp_table_name = `"TEMP_RtHSNMaster_`+ TEMP_TBL_ID +`"`;
```

OR fix the formatting on the system creating the input.

Here is the trimmed version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REPLICA_RtHSNMaster(PARAM_STG_SUFFIX VARCHAR, TEMP_TBL_ID VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '
  
var var_temp_table_name = `TEMP_RtHSNMaster_`+ TEMP_TBL_ID.trim();
  
var sql_command1 = `CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE ` + var_temp_table_name;
sql_command1 += ` AS SELECT * FROM RTHSNMASTER LIMIT 0 `;
       
snowflake.execute ( {sqlText: sql_command1} );

var sql_command2 =`COPY INTO ` + var_temp_table_name;
sql_command2 += ` FROM @DATA_FILE_S3_STAGE` + PARAM_STG_SUFFIX;
sql_command2 +=` PATTERN =$$.*RtHSNMaster_.*csv$$ FILE_FORMAT =(FORMAT_NAME =$$CSV_FORMAT$$ FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = $$"$$ TIMESTAMP_FORMAT =$$YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF$$);`;
       
snowflake.execute ({sqlText: sql_command2});
            
var sql_command3 =`DELETE FROM RTHSNMASTER using ` + var_temp_table_name;
sql_command3 += ` WHERE RTHSNMASTER.TENANTCODE=` + var_temp_table_name;
sql_command3 += `.TENANTCODE AND RTHSNMASTER.HSNID=` + var_temp_table_name;
sql_command3 += `.HSNID ; `;
       
snowflake.execute ( {sqlText: sql_command3} );

var sql_command4 =`INSERT INTO RTHSNMASTER SELECT * FROM ` + var_temp_table_name;
        
snowflake.execute ( {sqlText: sql_command4} );

var success = sql_command1 + `\r\n` + sql_command2 + `\r\n` + sql_command3 + `\r\n` + sql_command4 + `\r\n`; 

return  success;
';
```

```
call REPLICA_RTHSNMASTER ('A', ' 95');
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_RtHSNMaster_95 AS SELECT * FROM RTHSNMASTER LIMIT 0  

COPY INTO TEMP_RtHSNMaster_95 FROM @DATA_FILE_S3_STAGEA PATTERN =$$.*RtHSNMaster_.*csv$$ FILE_FORMAT =(FORMAT_NAME =$$CSV_FORMAT$$ FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = $$"$$ TIMESTAMP_FORMAT =$$YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF$$); 

DELETE FROM RTHSNMASTER using TEMP_RtHSNMaster_95 WHERE RTHSNMASTER.TENANTCODE=TEMP_RtHSNMaster_95.TENANTCODE AND RTHSNMASTER.HSNID=TEMP_RtHSNMaster_95.HSNID ;  

INSERT INTO RTHSNMASTER SELECT * FROM TEMP_RtHSNMaster_95
```